# Transferring Data from One View to Another

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, storyboard

I have one string in one view controller and trying to transfer its value that it has to another string in another view controller. Here is my code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
  if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Check Mark Segue"])
    {
    NSLog(@"Transferring Data");
   RenewDrop *controller = segue.destinationViewController;;
   controller.transferData = self.renewString;
    }
}
```

I thought this would work because it seems rather easy. However, Whenever I NSLog the transferData string in the next view it says that it is (null).

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

```
#RenewDrop.h

@interface RenewDrop : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate> {

NSString *transferData;
}

 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *transferData;


#RenewDrop.m

@implementation AutoRenewDrop
@synthesize transferData;
```

Comment: btw would also like to point out that I do set the renewString to having a value in -(viewDidLoad)

Comment: Is your destination view controller embedded in a navigation controller?

Comment: No it is not embedded with a navigation controller.

Comment: Why did you cast your `segue.destinationViewController` ?
Have you try to just use it without casting ?

Comment: I have changed it to now it is saying RenewDrop *controller = [[RenewDrop alloc] init]; if that is what you mean and it still gives me the same value of (null)

Comment: What i mean is `RenewDrop *controller = segue.destinationViewController`

Comment: Put a breakpoint at `controller.transferData = self.renewString;` and check that the value is being assigned. Alternatively, try to assign a static string like this `controller.transferData = @"test";`

Comment: Is the `transferData` property an IBOutlet?  If so, it will be overridden when the view is loaded.

Comment: @usergio2 I have changed it to the code you have said and it still does not work. Returns value of (null)

Comment: @JShapiro It is propertied and synthesized but not considered to be an IBOutlet

Comment: @user427969 I have put a breakpoint at the following and it has been assigned

Comment: @JShapiro Still no use. Tried and it is not null when assigned.

Comment: Add the following code in RenewDrop:

`- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"The value of transferData: %@", self.transferData);
}`

Comment: The value of transferData: (null)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18890/discussion-between-j-shapiro-and-zack)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so here is what happened: I had code in my viewDidLoad on Renew Drop that I didnt see:

```
//AddReminder *controller = [[AddReminder alloc] init];
//self.transferData = controller.renewString;
```

Once I did this everything worked just like above.

Thanks to everyone for the help!